# Python subprocess.Popen method not executing "start chrome" command

Tags: python

I tried executing `start chrome` in the command line and it worked.
However when I tried the same using subprocess.Popen(), throws a file not found error.

Please find blow the code and let me know the reason for the same.

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.Popen(['start','chrome'])
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try `sp.Popen(['start','chrome'], shell=True)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does subprocess.Popen not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823910/why-does-subprocess-popen-not-work)

Comment: "The only time you need to specify shell=True on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch file or console-based executable." -- [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). `start` is a shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `shell = True` in this case since `start` is a Windows built-in command.

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.Popen(['start','chrome'], shell=True)
```

Check [Running windows shell commands with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python) for detail.

Answer (score 1):

I can not tell you why it does not work with subprocess, but if you do not rely on it, try os:

```
import os
os.system("start chrome")
```